# How to make input.error work on all fields?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, forms

http://jsfiddle.net/Nvt2h/

I am using this script which sends details from input fields to my email. As you can see, there is input.error which highlights the field in red if there is an incorrect entry. However, this currently works only for Field 1 and Field 4.

How can I make this work on field 2 and 3 as well ?

```
<form id="contact" name="contact" action="#" method="post">
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="msg">Field1:

    </label>
    <input name="msg" type="msg" class="form-control" id="msg">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="id">Field2:</label>
    <input name="id" type="msg" class="form-control" id="msg">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="pb">Field3:

    </label>
    <input name="pb" type="msg" class="form-control" id="pb">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="email">Field4:</label>
    <input name="email" type="email" class="form-control" id="email">
</div>
<button id="send">Submit</button>
```

Comment: input 1 and 2 have the same id

Comment: @Alex Yeah was trying to add that to see if it would help but it didn't. If they have different ID's, it doesn't work as well.

Comment: you are not applying any validation to those fields. what do you want validate

Comment: your script does not validate those fields, how shall there be errors then?!

Comment: what validation do you want to apply to those fields

Comment: @Arun P Johny I want to validate it same as Field 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a minlength attribute to those input fields

```
<input name="msg" type="msg" class="form-control msg" id="msg" minlength="2">
```

then

```
function validateEmail(email) {
    var reg = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
    return reg.test(email);
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    //$(".modalbox").fancybox();
    $("#contact").submit(function () {
        return false;
    });


    $("#send").on("click", function () {
        $('#contact input.error').removeClass('error');

        var emailval = $("#email").val();
        var mailvalid = validateEmail(emailval);
        if (mailvalid == false) {
            $("#email").addClass("error");
        }

        var minlen = $('#contact input[minlength]').filter(function(){
            return this.value.length < +$(this).attr('minlength')
        }).addClass('error').length;

        if (mailvalid == true && minlen == 0) {
            // if both validate we attempt to send the e-mail
            // first we hide the submit btn so the user doesnt click twice
            $("#send").replaceWith("<p><strong>Sending, please wait...</strong></p>");

            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'send.php',
                data: $("#contact").serialize(),
                dataType: 'jsonp',
                success: function (data) {
                    if (data.result == true) {
                        $("#contact").fadeOut("fast", function () {
                            $(this).before("<p class='success'><strong>Thank you, your message has been sent. We will be in touch shortly.</strong></p>");
                        });
                    } else { /* if you want to handle mail send failed, put it here */
                    }
                },
                error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    // this is triggered if there's a problem getting the jsonp back from the server
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/343qA/)

Comment: Thank you. Do you also know how I could replace Field 1 with <select> so user select the answer and it still deliver it to email when selected.

Comment: @user3187469 can you edit the fiddle to recreate what you want